# mongodump for collection larger than ram

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I am using a command like this to dump data from a remote machine:

```
mongodump --verbose \
          --uri="mongodb://mongousr:somepassword@host.domain.com:27017/somedb?authSource=admin" \
          --out="$BACKUP_PATH"
```

This fails like so:

```
Failed: error writing data for collection `somedb.someCollection` to disk: error reading collection: EOF
```

`somedb.someCollection` is about 40GB. I don't have the ability to increase RAM to this size.

I have seen two explanations. One is that the console output is too verbose and fills the RAM. This seems absurd, it's only a few kilobytes and it's on the client machine anyway. Rejected (but I am trying it again now with `--quiet` just to be sure).

The more plausible explanation is that the host fills its RAM with `somedb.someCollection` data and then fails. The problem is that the 'solution' that I've seen proposed is to increase the RAM to be bigger than the size of the collection.

Really? That can't be right. What's the point of mongodump with that limitation?

The question: is it possible to mongodump a database with a collection that is larger than my RAM size? How?

mongodump Client:

```
macOS
mongodump --version
mongodump version: 4.0.3
git version: homebrew
Go version: go1.11.4
   os: darwin
   arch: amd64
   compiler: gc
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2r  26 Feb 2019
```

Server:

```
built with docker FROM mongo:
Reports: MongoDB server version: 4.0.8
```

Comment: There is no requirement to have more RAM than collection data in order to be able to run `mongodump`. I suspect your issue is related to detecting available RAM in your Docker deployment. As per the [MongoDB Production Notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/): `If you run mongod in a container (e.g. lxc, cgroups, Docker, etc.) that does not have access to all of the RAM available in a system, you must set storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB to a value less than the amount of RAM available in the container.` The default is 50% of (available RAM -1 GB).

Comment: Alternatively you could try upgrading to MongoDB 4.0.9 which includes better detection for available RAM within containers, and should no longer require manual adjustment of the `cacheSizeGB` setting.

Answer (score 3):

Simply dump your collection slice by slice:

```
mongodump --verbose \
          --uri="mongodb://mongousr:somepassword@host.domain.com:27017/somedb?authSource=admin" \
          --out="$BACKUP_PATH" -q '{_id: {$gte: ObjectId("40ad7bce1a3e827d690385ec")}}'

mongodump --verbose \
          --uri="mongodb://mongousr:somepassword@host.domain.com:27017/somedb?authSource=admin" \
          --out="$BACKUP_PATH" -q '{_id: {$lt: ObjectId("40ad7bce1a3e827d690385ec")}}'
```

or partitioning your dump by a different query set on _id or some different field. The reported _id is a mere example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In your example, both calls to mongodump are writing into the same output directory. Are separate files created for the two ‘slices’? When restoring, do I need to make two calls to mongorestore? I’m having trouble reconciling this approach with my traditional notion of a database backup and restore, e.g. pgdump.

Comment: You have to use two different backup paths, otherwise you are getting the second .bson file overwriting the first one. There is the --archive option to write the backup on the file you want, but using this option you have to use anyway different paths because, owing to a bug, the second dump deletes the metadata file for your collection, so you can't restore your collection. Of course when using mongorestore you need one command for each dump (folder) you have previously created.

Answer (score 3):

[Stennie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1388319/stennie)'s answer really works.

The default value of `storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB` is `max((RAM-1GB)/2, 256MB)`. If your mongodb server is running in a docker container with default configs, and there are other apps running in the host machine, the memory could be full filled when you are dumping a large collection. The same thing can happen if the containers' RAM is limited due to your configs.

You can use `docker run --name some-mongo -d mongo --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 1.5` (the number is based on you situation).

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to add the compress flag to the output of mongodump. It helped me to backup a db that hanged at 48% without compressing. So the syntax would be:

```
mongodump --uri="mongodb://mongousr:somepassword@host.domain.com:27017/somedbauthSource=admin"  --gzip --out="$BACKUP_PATH"
```